# Generating specific symbol after send form

Tags: php, html, forms, send

I am lookin for some easy way to make *variable* or *specific* symbol, simple some *unique* **number** after user send simple ordering form.

eg.
Person write his name, surname, email..., click on "send" & on next "sent screen" he will see that **number** (Thanks for your informations, you specific symbol is: **XXXXXXXXXX** (edit. for example: 12345678901))

Comment: FYI: X's are not numbers

Comment: hah, it was example :D :D

Answer (score 1):

If you need an *alpha-numeric* code, you can use `uniqid` ([Source](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php)):

```
printf("uniqid(): %s\r\n", uniqid());  // 4b3403665fea6
```

If you store the data from the form, you also can do something with the sequence-attributed number you may have obtain after insertion.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an integer string:

```
function getRandInt($length) {
    $start = pow(10, $length - 1);
    $end = ( pow(10, $length) ) - 1;

    return rand($start, $end);
}
```

Or, if you want a alpha numeric one:

```
function getRandStr($length, $encryption_level = 5) {
    $str = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $encryption_level; $i++) {
        $str = base64_encode(md5(time()) . $str);
    }
    return substr($str, 0, $length);
}
```